# EYE(Retina) Scanning in Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, scanning

I'm an android developer. Currently I'm learning Google Glass App development. I want to know, is there any API available for retina scan or eye scanning in google glass.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no special API for Glass specifically that has eye scanning.

After doing some looking around, I found some posts about something called bioapi, but when I tried to go to the link given to this supposed API, bioapi.org, the page doesn't seem to exist. Then again, the post was from 4 years ago ([if i wanted to perform an iris scan, would i need any additional api's or can i just use whats readily available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761761/if-i-wanted-to-perform-an-iris-scan-would-i-need-any-additional-apis-or-can-i)). The best thing I could find is that wikipedia page for the api: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BioAPI.

To be honest, I don't think it is a very practical idea. A lot of people seem to be interested in using facial recognition on Glass as well, and the issue is that for it to work properly, you need to have near perfect conditions. I don't think that the algorithms seem to handle suboptimal conditions, such as  a poorly lit room, or shaking camera (as it would be if a person is walking down the street) very well.

I would think that iris scanning from Glass would be even harder than facial recognition. First of all the libraries are probably much more obscure and hard to find. Once you do find the libraries, you'd need some great lighting and probably have the subject being scanned stand absolutely still and fairly close to the camera.

At the present state, maybe it'd be best to look for another way to do this.